# Getting end date from start date

Tags: oracle

I have a EMP table in my database with the following fields:

```
id,name,post,joining_date.
```

Whenever any employees designation changes, a new row inserted with new designation. Means there are multiple rows for an employee if he got any promotion. Now i want to get end date designation wise for each employee.Like if my date is like :

```
id        name          start_date     post
1          x             24-JAN-05      Software Engineer
2          y             23-JAN-08      Associate Software Engineer
3          x             26-Aug-05      Senior Sofware Engineer
4          y             20-FEB-09      Sofware Engineer
```

I want data in following format :

```
id        name          start_date     end_date        post
1          x             24-JAN-05      26-Aug-05      Software Engineer
2          x             26-Aug-05      null           Senior Software Engineer
3          y             23-JAN-08      20-FEB-09       Associate Software Engineer
4          y             20-FEB-09       null           Software Engineer
```

So I want to get data with end date for each designation for each employee. I dont want to use PL/SQL. I want to use only query.I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here we go:

```
select id, name, start_date, lead(start_date) over (partition by name
order by start_date) as end_date, post from emp;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `LEAD` analytic function for this

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       start_date,
       LEAD(start_date) over (partition by name
                                  order by start_date) end_date,
       post
  FROM emp
```

Presumably, though, in your real table, you have some sort of `EMPLOYEE_ID` that you can use rather than using the `NAME` to determine which rows go together.  Otherwise, as soon as you have two employees named 'John Smith`, this will cause problems.